# Changing the refresh logic webView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview

You need to change the approach of updating the page by swiping to the bottom,
where the update should occur at the top of the webView, which is limited to 100px.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        setupWebView();
        setupGestureDetector();
        setupSwipeRefresh();
    }

    private void setupWebView() {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebView(this));

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
                return super.onCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
            }

        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
        }

        String ua = webSettings.getUserAgentString()
                .replace("; wv", "");

        int uaIndex = ua.indexOf("Version");

        ua = ua.substring(0, uaIndex)
                .concat(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .concat(ua.substring(uaIndex));

        webSettings.setUserAgentString(ua);

        webView.loadUrl("");


    }

    private void setupGestureDetector() {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                if (e1 != null && e2 != null) {
                    if (e1.getY() <= 50 && distanceY < 0) { // check for swipe down at the top
                        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        webView.reload();
                    }
                }
                return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void setupSwipeRefresh() {
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (webView.getScrollY() == 0) {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (mySwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

.................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For now, the standard SwipeRefreshLayout logic works.

What's wrong with the code and markup?
How to get it to work as it should?

Please help to solve this problem.